# Web scraping Linkedin Job posts using Python, Selenium & Phantomjs

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, phantomjs, python-3.6

Some LinkedIn job posts contain a `see more` button that expands the whole job description: 
https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/401243784/?refId=3024203031501300167509&trk=d_flagship3_search_srp_jobs

I tried to expand it using the `element.click()` but the source I get after expansion contains some placeholder divs instead of the original div. How, can I scrap those hidden texts.
This is what I get from `driver.page_source`

```
<div class="jobs-ghost-placeholder jobs-ghost-placeholder--medium jobs-ghost-placeholder--thin mb2"></div>
      <div class="jobs-ghost-placeholder jobs-ghost-placeholder--x-small jobs-ghost-placeholder--thin mb2"></div>
      <div class="jobs-ghost-placeholder jobs-ghost-placeholder--small jobs-ghost-placeholder--thin"></div>
```

Instead of the source I get from chrome inspect:

```
  <div id="ember7189" class="jobs-description-details pt5 ember-view">    <h3 class="jobs-box__sub-title js-formatted-exp-title">Seniority Level</h3>
    <p class="jobs-box__body js-formatted-exp-body">Associate</p>

<!---->
    <h3 class="jobs-box__sub-title js-formatted-industries-title">Industry</h3>
    <ul class="jobs-box__list jobs-description-details__list js-formatted-industries-list">
        <li class="jobs-box__list-item jobs-description-details__list-item">Real Estate</li>
        <li class="jobs-box__list-item jobs-description-details__list-item">Information Technology and Services</li>
    </ul>

    <h3 class="jobs-box__sub-title js-formatted-employment-status-title">Employment Type</h3>
    <p class="jobs-box__body js-formatted-employment-status-body">Full-time</p>

    <h3 class="jobs-box__sub-title js-formatted-job-functions-title">Job Functions</h3>
    <ul class="jobs-box__list jobs-description-details__list js-formatted-job-functions-list">
        <li class="jobs-box__list-item jobs-description-details__list-item">Information Technology</li>
        <li class="jobs-box__list-item jobs-description-details__list-item">Project Management</li>
        <li class="jobs-box__list-item jobs-description-details__list-item">Product Management</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I also tried different values for the wait `WebDriverWait(driver, 3)` but in vain.

code:

```
employment_type = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located(
                        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.jobs-description__details>div.jobs-description-details>p.js-formatted-employment-status-body'))).text
```

raises timeout exception as it only finds those jobs-ghost-placeholder instead of the described css_selector

Comment: On the URL "https://www.linkedin.com/jobs/view/401243784/?refId=3024203031501300167509&trk=d_flagship3_search_srp_jobs" I can find only one `see more` button and that's within `People also searched` section. Not from the place you provided the HTML. Thanks

Comment: Are you using a premium account? I do see the see more button and it appears in the page source too when I use selenium.

Comment: What exactly do you mean `see more button` too `when I use selenium`. No, mine is not a `premium account` and I didn't even login. Thanks

Comment: `driver.page_source` outputs the `see more` button in it when I run the script.

Comment: You can find `n` number of `see more` text but not necessarily they are all `buttons` or `links`. Half of them may be `hidden` as well. Thanks

Comment: well... 
```<button aria-controls="company-description-text" aria-expanded="false" data-control-name="see_more" class="view-more-icon" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-3660="3660" data-is-animating-click="true">
    <span>See more</span>
    <--truncated-->
  </button>```
notice the button has aria-controls="company-description-text" . This button can be identified using the parent divs as well. using this code:
`driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.cta-wrap>button.view-more-icon').click()`

Comment: Nopes, firebug doesn't finds anything by that css. Can you update your exact manual steps to reproduce your issue? Thanks